# Why does Simple JWT work for one user but not another in djangorestframework?

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

While I am using Simple JWT for djangorestframework it is working with one user and for another user it is saying like
{
"detail": "User not found",
"code": "user_not_found"
}

view.py code:

```
class RegisterView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = RegisterSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()

            refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user=user)
            return Response(
                {
                'status':200,
                'message':'Phone Number Registered Successfully',
                'refresh':str(refresh),
                'access': str(refresh.access_token)
                }
            )
        return Response(serializer.errors)


class SetMpinView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated,]
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication,]

    def put(self, request):
        phone_number = request.data.get('phone_number')
        device_id = request.data.get('device_id')

        if not phone_number:
            return Response({'status': 400, 'message':'phone number required'})

        try:
            registered_phone = Register.objects.get(phone_number=phone_number, device_id=device_id)
        except Register.DoesNotExist:
            return Response({'status': 400, 'message':'invalid phone number'})

        serializer = SetMpinSerializer(registered_phone, data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({'status':200, 'message':'MPIN Successfully Created'})
        return Response({'status':400, 'message':'Invalid'})
```

How can solve this problem